# RegEX: Matching everything but a specific value

Tags: regex

How do i match everything in an html response but this piece of text
"signed_request" value="The signed_request is placed here"

Comment: It is probably a simple fix from what you have already written; maybe if you showed what that was...

Comment: What language/tool you're trying to use it within? And what do you mean by "grab"? Get a string containing everything but that exact text? Are you sure it's a job for a regex?

Comment: @Deltharis Yes get a string of everything except that exact text, considering that the text between the last two quotation marks is random. I'm using the Charles Debugging Proxy rewrite tool which supports RegEx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fast solution is:

^(.*?)"signed_request" value="The signed_request is placed here"(.*)$

If value can be random text you could do:

^(.*?)"signed_request" value="[^"]*"(.*)$

This will generate two groups that.
If the result was not successful the text does not contain the word.
If the text contains the text more than once, it is only the first time that is ignored.

If you need to remove all instances of the text you can just as well use a replace string method.

But usually it is a bad idea to use regex on html.

Comment: The text between the last quotation marks is random, How do i go about that?

Comment: Well i'm using a software called Charles, and what i'm exactly trying to do is to replace everything in the response with blank text to only the signed request..There is an image of the software and how i tried your code   http://s22.postimg.org/ve8xr97ht/Chls_Stack.png

Comment: You should have said in your question what you really want to do. In order to replace everything but you do not write an expression to grab everything but.

Comment: Should i edit the question? What should i say instead?